# Reason for Factory Pattern

Tags: design-patterns

Below is a  reason which is given in a book to assigning a Factory helper class to delegate creation of objects due to complexity of object creations. 
That is "**Conditionally creating of objects from one of a family of similar classes based upon some external property value**". 
I cant figure out this situation. Can anyone help by giving an example for above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At my company we deal with microphones and multiple platforms.

We have a factory method along the lines of `createMicrophoneRecorderSource(...)`

On Linux, we create an ALSA microphone. On Windows we use WASAPI and on iOS we use... native iOS stuff which I don't remember the exact name.

The user doesn't have to bother about knowing what is what, we hide all the gory details inside the factory.

Answer (score 1):

A factory is anything that makes an object.  A constructor is already a factory.  If you need other ways to make an object, you make more factories.  Sometimes you make them outside the class itself, if the extra behavior depends on things the class shouldn't need to care about.